# css formatting in php

Tags: php, css

I have a css question.
I have the following php code which displays a name.

```
 while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print $db_field['ship_name'] . "<BR>";
```

I'm trying to add some text style to it but I'm not that good in css and I'm somehow lost.
I'm trying to do something like `<t> $db_field['ship_name'].<t/>` but it gives me an error.

Comment: <t> is not a valid CSS style, what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: i have them defined in my css file such ass :   t {
font-size: 50pt;
 color:black;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;}
  .... im trying to style the output from the php code.

Comment: You should include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

judging by your comment, probably you want

```
print "<span class='t'>".$db_field['ship_name']."</span><BR>";
```

and for your CSS file define

```
.t {  font-size: 50pt; color:black; text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white; }
```

Comment: print "<t>".$db_field['ship_name']."</t><BR>";

Comment: my css : t {
font-size: 50pt;
 color:black;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;}

Answer (score 0):

This will echo out the data into a span tag:

```
echo "<span>" . $db_field['ship_name'] . "</span>";
```

To add a css class:

```
echo "<span class=\"class_name\">" . $db_field['ship_name'] . "</span>";
```

Then in your css file:

```
span.class_name { font-size:24px; color:#666; }
```

Comment: a table cell interferes with my design, is there any way to apply the formatting directly to the text?

Comment: You're going to want to do it via css and not in the actual html that the php is outputting. I think you should look at a css primer, if you're unfamiliar. There are a ton of resources on the web.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a table cell either. You could output into a list, paragraph, or whatever html tag you need to use. That will eleviate the need for the BR tag. Ultimately, you want to use css for styling. Makes life so much easier.

Comment: @user964535 If it's not in a table then use a `<span>` tag instead of a `<td>` tag.  That's as close as you can get to "directly to the text", `<span>` is an inline element so it will not disrupt the page flow.

Comment: my apologies but i was not using a <td> merely a styled css that i happened to name <t>. im sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this. Either you embed html in PHP or write separate HTML snippet. I will show you the both ways :
 The first one is already explained above in the answer by sinclairchase.

```
echo "<td>" . $db_field['ship_name'] . "</td>";
```

The other way is :

```
<?php while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
   <td>
      <?php print $db_field['ship_name'] . "<BR>"; ?>
   </td>
 <?php  }  ?>
```

I dont unsderstand why you write t in question it would be td.